# Programmatically blocking all connections between a process and particular host in C#/Windows

Tags: c#, windows, sockets

I'm trying to track down some failover problems in a third-party connector library that we use.  At the moment I am starting and stopping remote services to simulate the failures, this works but is very impractical.

Is there a way that I can programmatically block all connections between a process and a given host?

EDIT: as well as blocking I'd like to drop any existing connections

Comment: How about blocking the socket?

Comment: @AseemGautam - sounds good, how can I do that programatically?

Comment: There is a 'Blocking' property in Socket class.

Comment: @AseemGautam Sorry, 'blocking' might have been a misleading term to choose, I meant it in terms of disabling/dropping the connections.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you can interact with the windows Firewall to achieve what you want ( programmatically block all connections between a process and a given host), take a look at the [Windows Firewall Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366449%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can also block all connection to the host by writing an entry in the [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file. You can just redirect the host name to localhost or whatever unreachable address. But it doesn't apply to a single process but to the whole machine. It's more simple than working with firewall, but more global.

Comment: Good idea but unfortunately any existing connections will persist

Comment: so the only way is the firewall, as stated by aleroot above